# Manual Titleize in Ruby 2.3.3

Tags: ruby, rspec, capitalize

I'm trying to .capitalize all string inputs, excluding small words such as "Of", "The" or "And".

I can't figure out why the code isn't working properly.

```
def titleize(x)
  capitalized = x.split.each do |i|
    if i.length >= 2
      if i == "of" || "the" || "and"
        next
      else
        i.capitalize!
      end
    else
      next
    end
  end
  capitalized.join(' ')
end
```

Here's my Rspec output:

Failures:

```
 1) Simon says titleize capitalizes a word
 Failure/Error: expect(titleize("jaws")).to eq("Jaws")

   expected: "Jaws"
        got: "jaws"

   (compared using ==)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a `string literal in condition` warning in:

```
if i == "of" || "the" || "and"
```

You're trying to compare `i` with `of` or `the` or `and`, but after the first try, you're not passing a left value to compare, try with:

```
if i == "of" || i == "the" || i == "and"
```

More idiomatic Ruby would be to use `include?`

```
if ['of', 'the', 'and'].include?(i)
```

This way at least you get `Jaws`

The reason because your actual method doesn't work for the string `war and peace` is because if the length of the word being passed is minor or equal than 2 then it'll execute `next`, so, it'll only capitalize the word `peace`.

Comment: How can I exclude the first element in the array? i[0].capitalize! seems to get overwritten everywhere I try

Comment: The first element in an iteration?, try using an index, in your case `each_with_index`, take a look to this `[1,2,3].each_with_index{|e,i| p e unless i.zero?}`